# how to get the column count which is having a particular value in a data frame using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns .

```
Sales   Close_Date
0       04/01/12
0   
33496   12/01/12
588     05/01/12
9240    10/01/12
```

how to find out out number of "0" or "9296" or any other value present in "Sales" column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(df.Sales)
c[0]

2
```

Comment: I think this solution is very slow in bigger df :(

Comment: @Sidhartha I added this solution to show the breadth of python.  But almost certainly, the answers provided by jezrael are quicker.  Not to mention that his answer was far more informative.  In addition, upvoting answers in which others have put effort into and ***are helpful*** would be appreciated by all.

Answer (score 1):

If need count one value only the simpliest is sum `True` values of boolean mask:

```
print (df.Sales == 0)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Sales, dtype: bool


a = (df.Sales == 0).sum()
print (a)
2
```

And if need count all values need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Sales').size()
print (df)
Sales
0        2
588      1
9240     1
33496    1
dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
df = df['Sales'].value_counts()
print (df)
0        2
9240     1
588      1
33496    1
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

---

Use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if need filter:

```
df = df.query('Sales == 0')
print (df)
   Sales Close_Date
0      0   04/01/12
1      0        NaN
```

Or:

```
df = df[df.Sales == 0]
print (df)
   Sales Close_Date
0      0   04/01/12
1      0        NaN
```

**Timings**:

```
#[500000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [37]: %timeit ((df.Sales == 0).sum())
The slowest run took 4.18 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 4.62 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit (Counter(df.Sales)[0])
10 loops, best of 3: 82.4 ms per loop
```

but this can be faster:

```
a = (df.Sales.value == 0).sum()
```

Comment: ..I was looking for this solution                                                                       a = (df.Sales == 0).sum()
print (a)
2 . But it is only working for integer values if a column is contains string values then how to get the count .

Comment: It need only add `''` like `a = (df.Sales == 'value').sum()`

Comment: I think `Counter` solution in pandas is very slow, please check my timings.

Comment: @Sidhartha the `sum` is acting on a boolean array.  That will treat it appropriately.